# Set the XML file for Layout design according IPhone screen widgets

Tags: android

I want this type of layout how i can do this
[image]

all the titles should be clickable

please help me

I used Button and TextView but it seems very dull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate a LinearLayout with a TextView and an image (the right arrow). That LinearLayout must have clickable="true" and onClick="methodYouLike"

To identify what is being clicked you can add a tag to each, with an id, like android:tag="1", android:tag="2" ...

On the Activity onClick receives a View, só you can get that view, an obtain the tag, and do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not content with the standard UI you can always write your own custom widgets. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for some more information.

Answer (score 1):

Aso if you need not only 4 items but many, you can use [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) 
 You can provide a layout resource id and it will be atomatically inflated into each row. Datasource could be as DB so array and so on.